# Distinct() method does not work?

Tags: linq, distinct, duplication

I tried to use Distinct() to filter my collection to prevent duplication but my linq query still adds the same values to list.

thanks in advance.

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> CollectTopicsFromXml()
    {
         ObservableCollection<string> oc = new ObservableCollection<string>();
         XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
         var topicColl = xDoc.Descendants("topic").Distinct();


         foreach (var topic in topicColl)
         {
             oc.Add(topic.Value);
         }

        return oc;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Distinct` by default uses reference equality unless `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) are overridden on the item type.  Since `Equals` is not overridden for `XElement` each element is "distinct" regardless of its contents.

If you want distinct elements by `Name` or some other property (or combination of properties) you have a few options:

- Project the elements to an anonymous type which *does* implement value equality by default:

  ```
  var topicColl = xDoc.Descendants("topic")
                      .Select(e => new {e.Name, e.Value})
                      .Distinct();
  ```
- Use `GroupBy`, which allows an expression to be passed in
- Create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<XElement>` in the way that you want and pass that to `Distinct`
- Use `DistinctBy` from [MoreLinq](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/) which also allows an equality expression to be passed in